# PHP character encoding issue

Tags: php, wordpress, character-encoding

When I grab the title from my Word Press posts in code and pass them around as email, the punctuation gets a bit mangled.

For example `"TAMAGOTCHI P’S LOVE & MELODY SET"` comes out as `"TAMAGOTCHI P&#8217;S LOVE &#038; MELODY SET"`.

Any ideas how I prevent this?

Let me know if you need to see the specific code I'm currently using. (I'm not really sure if this is a WordPress issue, or a PHP issue.

**EDIT**
What happens is that this title is passed to a form via the query string. Then when the form is submitted, I take the string from the form field and email it.

So I guess I need to decode the html either before I pass it into the form field, or else before I email it.

**EDIT 2**
Weird, so I looked closer at the code and I'm already doing a urldecode before I pass the value into the form field

```
jQuery('#product_name').val("<?php echo urldecode(strip_tags($_GET['pname'])); ?>
```

Is there some default encoding happening when you serialize (for ajax formhandler)

```
    var dataString = $(this).serialize();
```

**EDIT 3** 
OK turns out the code is more complex. Title is also passed to some kind of wordpress session before it's hits the form. I'll figure it out where exactly I need to put urldecode. Thanks!

Comment: it's not mangled. that's html-encoded quotes. you can check each stage to see where the encoding occurs. when it comes out of the db, when wp hands over to email, etc...

Comment: I want to un-html-encoded it (html-decode?). I'll search around for how to do that in PHP, but do let me know if it's something you may be able to share!

Comment: Try http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php

Comment: Can you try replacing with this: `<?php echo html_entity_decode(strip_tags($_GET['pname']), ENT_QUOTES ); ?>`

Answer (score 1):

This is one WordPress "feature" I could do without.

Here's one down-n-dirty method to get the fancy quotes (or other entities) replaced:

```
$title = get_the_title( get_the_ID() );
$title = str_replace( '&#8217', "'", $title );
echo $title;
```

We could integrate deeper, by hooking into `the_title`, if you want this same de-entities functionality throughout the site. This code block would belong in your theme's `functions.php` file.

```
function reform_title($title, $id) {
    $title = str_replace( '&#8217', "'", $title );
    return $title;
}
add_filter('the_title', 'reform_title', 10, 2);
```

Comment: ah, would hate to do this for each possible glyph. Would this work? mb_convert_encoding($string, "UTF-8", "HTML-ENTITIES");

Comment: @MaxHodges this would get you closer: `$title = html_entity_decode($title, ENT_QUOTES );` but I don't think it addresses all entities, either.

Comment: posted another edit (Edit 2) to question. Still don't understand what's going on but maybe getting closer...

Answer (score 0):

Im not really sure about wordpress, but the issue itself its that the text its coming out as URLENCODE instead of a UTF-8 or other encode.

You have two options

1. When you receive the text you never turn it back to normal encoding (Which is weird as usually is de-encoded by php when you access the $_GET or $_POST variables)
2. You are parsing the message with the urlencode() function.